# String operations with stringr not working depending on vectorized/unvectorized call

Tags: r, if-statement, vectorization, stringr

I'm struggling understanding why my code below works only when using `rowwise` in combination with `ifelse`. Or more precisely, I think I get why it is working in that scenario, but not why it doesn't simply work with `if_else`.

What I'm doing is, I'm checking if a certain rows contains the word "infile" or "outfile" and if it has a relative path (".."). If it does have the words "infile/outfile" and not a relative path, then it has an absolute path "C:". And in that case, I want to replace the user name with something else (here: "test").

Any ideas?

### Data:

```
df <- structure(list(value = c("infile 'C:\\Users\\USER\\folder\\Data.sav'", 
"infile '..\\folder\\Data.sav'", "outfile '..\\folder\\Data.sav'", 
"test", "")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

user_name <- "test"
```

### Code that works:

```
df |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(value = ifelse(str_detect(value, "infile|outfile") & !str_detect(value, "\\'\\.\\.\\\\"),
                        str_replace(value,
                                    str_sub(value,
                                            str_locate_all(value, "\\\\")[[1]][2] + 1,
                                            str_locate_all(value, "\\\\")[[1]][3] - 1),
                                    user_name),
                        value)) |> 
  ungroup()
```

with output:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 1
  value                                       
  <chr>                                       
1 "infile 'C:\\Users\\test\\folder\\Data.sav'"
2 "infile '..\\folder\\Data.sav'"             
3 "outfile '..\\folder\\Data.sav'"            
4 "test"                                      
5 ""
```

### Code that doesn't work:

```
df |> 
  mutate(value = if_else(str_detect(value, "infile|outfile") & !str_detect(value, "\\'\\.\\.\\\\"),
                        str_replace(value,
                                    str_sub(value,
                                            str_locate_all(value, "\\\\")[[1]][2] + 1,
                                            str_locate_all(value, "\\\\")[[1]][3] - 1),
                                    user_name),
                        value))
```

I think this works, but gives a warning message:

```
Warning messages:
1: Problem while computing `value = if_else(...)`.
ℹ empty search patterns are not supported 
2: Problem while computing `value = if_else(...)`.
ℹ empty search patterns are not supported
```

### Code that doesn't work:

```
df |> 
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(value = if_else(str_detect(value, "infile|outfile") & !str_detect(value, "\\'\\.\\.\\\\"),
                        str_replace(value,
                                    str_sub(value,
                                            str_locate_all(value, "\\\\")[[1]][2] + 1,
                                            str_locate_all(value, "\\\\")[[1]][3] - 1),
                                    user_name),
                        value)) |> 
  ungroup()

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `value = if_else(...)`.
ℹ The error occurred in row 2.
Caused by error:
! Empty `pattern` not supported
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the issue is that `if_else()` evaluates both the true and false output in every row, while `ifelse()` only evaluates the true and false expressions where they are used.

Also, if you don't use `rowwise()`, then mutate passes the whole set of strings in `df$value` on each iteration, and then returns the same indices for the beginning and ending of the string for each row.

To debug, I'd suggest breaking the calculation out a bit:

```
df %>% rowwise() %>%
       mutate(n=length(value), slen=str_length(value),
              l1=str_locate_all(value,"\\\\")[[1]][2]+1,
              l2=str_locate_all(value,"\\\\")[[1]][3]-1, 
              ssub=str_sub(value, l1, l2), 
              detect=str_detect(value, "infile|outfile")& !str_detect(value,"\\'\\.\\.\\\\"), 
              vout=if_else(detect, ssub, user_name))
# A tibble: 5 × 8
# Rowwise: 
  value                                            n  slen    l1    l2 ssub   detect vout 
  <chr>                                        <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <lgl>  <chr>
1 "infile 'C:\\Users\\USER\\folder\\Data.sav'"     1    38    18    21 "USER" TRUE   USER 
2 "infile '..\\folder\\Data.sav'"                  1    27    19    10 ""     FALSE  test 
3 "outfile '..\\folder\\Data.sav'"                 1    28    20    11 ""     FALSE  test 
4 "test"                                           1     4    NA    NA  NA    FALSE  test 
5 ""                                               1     0    NA    NA  NA    FALSE  test
```

While without the `rowwise()`, mutate gets all the strings in the value column all at once, and it finds the same locations for your cuts on *every single row*:

```
df %>% 
       mutate(n=length(value), slen=str_length(value),
              l1=str_locate_all(value,"\\\\")[[1]][2]+1,
              l2=str_locate_all(value,"\\\\")[[1]][3]-1, 
              ssub=str_sub(value, l1, l2), 
              detect=str_detect(value, "infile|outfile")& !str_detect(value,"\\'\\.\\.\\\\"), 
              vout=if_else(detect, ssub, user_name))
# A tibble: 5 × 8
  value                                            n  slen    l1    l2 ssub    detect vout 
  <chr>                                        <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <lgl>  <chr>
1 "infile 'C:\\Users\\USER\\folder\\Data.sav'"     5    38    18    21 "USER"  TRUE   USER 
2 "infile '..\\folder\\Data.sav'"                  5    27    18    21 "\\Dat" FALSE  test 
3 "outfile '..\\folder\\Data.sav'"                 5    28    18    21 "r\\Da" FALSE  test 
4 "test"                                           5     4    18    21 ""      FALSE  test 
5 ""                                               5     0    18    21 ""      FALSE  test
```

Once you calculate the locations to subset your string incorrectly, I think you are just lucky that `if_else` threw a different error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way (where my substitution of `USER` is very simple; not sure if it should be more generic):

```r
df %>% 
    tidyr::separate(value, into = c('Type', 'Path'), sep = ' ') %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(
        Value = dplyr::if_else(
            (Type %in% c('infile', 'outfile')) & !startsWith(Path, "'.."),
            stringr::str_replace(Path, 'USER', user_name),
            Path
        )
    )
```

I split the `value` column to make the check easier.

If you need to replace the username with the variable you can do like this (here with back referencing the regular expression):

```r
df %>% 
    tidyr::separate(value, into = c('Type', 'Path'), sep = ' ') %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(
        Value = dplyr::if_else(
            (Type %in% c('infile', 'outfile')) & !startsWith(Path, "'.."),
            sub('^(C:\\\\Users\\\\)([[:alnum:]]+)\\\\', paste0('\\1', user_name, '\\\\'), Path),
            Path
        )
    )
```